# Convert Word document to XSL-FO

Tags: ms-word, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using Microsoft Word 2007. I would like to convert the Word document to XSL-FO. There are some hints on the net, but only for RenderX. Is there such a tool for Apache FOP?

Comment: XSL-FO is pretty standardized, and apart form some table stuff FOP should render it ok. Do you get error messages when trying to render the XSL-FO with Apache FOP?

Comment: In case you intend to use xsl-fo to produce pdf output, be aware that word 2007 and word2010 have the capability to "save as..." pdf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**RenderX** has a set of freely available [**XSLT Stylesheets for converting Microsoft's WordprocessingML documents to XSL FO (XSLFO)**](http://www.renderx.com/tools/word2fo.html)

These publicly available stylesheets can be used to convert Microsoft's WordprocessingML documents to XSL FO (XSLFO)

You don't have to use the generated XSL-FO with RenderX.  You can run them to produce XSL-FO output and render in any XSL-FO engine (to include Apache FOP).

**Antennahouse** also has a [WordMLToFO Stylesheet](http://www.antennahouse.com/product/wordmltofo.htm), but it is not free ($200)

Comment: RenderX ix quite expensive http://www.renderx.com/files/documents/RenderX_Published_Price_List.pdf

Comment: That may be the case, but the stylesheets are free

Comment: I downloaded the stylesheets, but it looks like to support Word 2003 version only?

Answer (score 2):

docx4j uses FOP to create pdfs from docx.

The XSLT is in [here](http://dev.plutext.org/svn/docx4j/trunk/docx4j/src/main/java/org/docx4j/convert/out/pdf/viaXSLFO/), but you may prefer to start with [this webapp, which can emit XSLFO from an uploaded docx](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/demo_landing.html).

It uses extension functions to do the heavy lifing, so it only really works as part of docx4j, but that's readily availableand ASLv2 licensed.

Yes, RenderX have their http://www.renderx.com/tools/word2fo.html but the licence is restrictive, and the 20070227 version is directed at Word 2003 WordML (maybe there is a newer one? its been a while since i looked)

Comment: How do I apply the XSLT to a Word document? It internally contains several Xml files, which one I should use?

Answer (score 1):

Word can do it on it's own.   Here are Microsoft's instructions: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa537167%28v=office.11%29.aspx#officewordwordmltoxsl-fo_creatinganxslfodocumentfromword

Here is the download link for the required XSL - Word2FO.xsl: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=16876

Comment: It's a very limited solution for Word 2003, not OpenXML. :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want DOCX (Word 2007) support you have to decompress the file and merge the individual resources in order to use the stylesheets. And that is half of the problem, because last time I checked there were severe limitations in the stylesheets like handling of styles/themes, continued sections and so on.
If you can afford it, a commercial [DOCX to PDF engine](http://www.ecrion.com) may be what you need.
One important thing to remember is that passing through XSL-FO is really not feasible as XSL-FO doesn't provide support for tabs, tight wrapping of text around images or other Word features.

Answer (score 0):

I created a while back a reporting tool that alters RenderX XSLT, that originally converts wordML 2003 to XSLFO, to do wordML 2003 -> XSLT, that later is merged with XML data to ultimately generate XSLFO with template + data. You needed to create your template in word, then import the generated XSLT to the web app and run the query that generates the XML and merges it with your provided template.

https://github.com/juanmf/neatReports

**Documentation**

https://github.com/juanmf/neatReports/blob/master/doc/HowToReport.pdf